# Nuget with generated web.config file

Tags: .net, powershell, nuget, package-managers

For my application web.config file is generated by [t4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). And as a result my config file is nested from web.tt file:

[image: web.config file location]

Now when I install elmah, for example, I get following output:

```
PM> Install-Package elmah
Successfully installed 'elmah 1.2.0.1'.
'web.config' already exists. Skipping...
'web.config' already exists. Skipping...
Successfully added 'elmah 1.2.0.1' to ProjectNameToken.Web.
```

And no configuration of elmah added to web.config file.
I verified that elmah section is not present in solution:

```
Find all "elmah", Subfolders, Find Results 1, "Entire Solution", ""
  Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 101
```

Any ideas why it happens? I know that nuget won't update my web.tt file, but at least web.config, is it possible?

**UPDATE**

Some details. This happens because web.config file has attribute

```
<DependentUpon>Web.tt</DependentUpon>
```

in csproj file. If I remove it everything works as expected.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the built in Config Transforms in VS?

Comment: Yes, some stubborn developers :(

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your setup mean the Web.config is *generated* from the .tt file? If so, NuGet is probably doing this because if it makes changes to your Web.Config, they'll just be overwritten when the file is next generated from the .tt file?

Comment: Yes, they will be overwritten, but I want to see them and move to .tt file.

Comment: I see. Can't think of a way around this :( Maybe worth posting in the NuGet forums: http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions to see if anyone has any ideas there